# How to make a slice to be able to convert *uint64 to *int64

Tags: go

I'm a beginner in using golang, I'm still confused about creating a slice for the child model, after that I want to take index "0" and convert it from *uint64 to *int64. Maybe i'm wrong way to convert the field, but i think i need to make the child model into a slice first before converting it. Here is the code :

```
params := category.PostAPICategoryParams{
    Data: category.PostAPICategoryBody{
        CategoryData: categoryTestData.CategoryData,
        Childs:       categoryTestData.Childs,
    },
}

result, _ := mainSuite.h.CreateCategory(mainSuite.rt, &params.Data.CategoryData, params.Data.Childs)

categoriesParamsTest := &category.GetAPICategoryParams{
    ParentID: // here is the code I need to write,
}
```

Here is the error when I try to write the code before creating the slice :
[image]

Comment: Do not post images of code. Edit the question to show the following: (1) the declaration for `ParentID` field in type `category.GetAPICategoryParams`, (2) the value that you want to assign to that field (3) and the type of that value (4) the exact text of the compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a pointer to a `uint64`, and want a pointer to a `int64`. There's no direct (safe) way to do this -- pointers to unsigned ints aren't compatible with pointers to signed ints -- but you can convert the pointed-at value to the right type (assuming the pointer isn't nil).

For example:

```
func convertUnsignedToSignedPointer64(p *uint64) *int64 {
    if p == nil { return nil }
    x := int64(*p)
    return &x
}
```

You can also do it via the `unsafe` package, although I prefer avoiding the `unsafe` package in code I write when possible:

```
func convertUnsignedToSignedPointer64(p *uint64) *int64 {
    return (*int64)(unsafe.Pointer(p))
}
```

This is ok via the rules given in [`unsafe.Pointer`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Pointer):

> (1) Conversion of a *T1 to Pointer to *T2.
>
> Provided that T2 is no larger than T1 and that the two share an
> equivalent memory layout, this conversion allows reinterpreting data
> of one type as data of another type.